Nest cli typeorm option removed for newer version
Need to find a command that can be used run npm:create
I have tried    "migration": "yarn typeorm migration:create -n",  "migration": "yarn typeorm migration:create -d path", and other options inclucing yarn.  And I am getting below error.
cli.js migration:create 
Creates a new migration file.
Positionals:
path  Path of the migration file                           [string] [required]
Options:
-h, --help       Show help                                           [boolean]
-o, --outputJs   Generate a migration file on Javascript instead of Typescript
[boolean] [default: false]
-t, --timestamp  Custom timestamp for the migration name
[number] [default: false]
-v, --version    Show version number                                 [boolean]
Unknown argument: config
error Command failed with exit code 1.

"migration:create": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:create".
This command worked for me. I think its esssentically because its doesn't convert to js.
